# Why I can't import private key to metamask?

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, metamask

I'm new. Sorry for maybe the stupid question.
Please, help me to understand why I can't import this private key to metamask:

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE8AF48A04CBFD47E8CB0366361
```

Well, I've changed couple of symbols.
Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you end up with so many hex FF's in the high-order bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE8AF48A04CBFD47E8CB0366361` although a valid 256-bit value, isn't a valid `secp256k1` private key.

Not all 256-bit strings are a formally valid private key; The key must be a positive integer less than , **the order of the largest prime order subgroup**.

i.e less than `FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141`